# Dynamic data table creation from a dymanic data source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to create a datatable on the fly from a another datable such that I need to iterate through all the rows of Table A, do calculations on the column values and write the results into the table B. For example table A has 5 columns (but in reality the number of columns varies) starting with the second column (A), each column has a numeric value. I need to add them up and write the total into table B.

Witht this the munber of clumns in table B will change in compared to table A but not rows. This data is not going to be displayed on the page as in a gridview or similar form so I can't use an OnEvent method, so please don't suggest other alternate ways, because the next process it requires a datatable to produce the desired outcome.

```
            | A | B | C   | D | E |        (table A)
    -------------------------------
    Entries | 2 | 6 | 100 | 0 | 5 |


            | Totals |                      (table B)
    Entries | 113    |
```

I've seen several examples suggesting progamatic data creation with this type of code:

```
DataTable dt; 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 


    dt = new DataTable("tblTest"); 
    DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn(); 
    dc1.DataType = typeof(String); 
    dc1.ColumnName = "Name"; 
    DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn(); 
    dc2.DataType = typeof(String); 
    dc2.ColumnName = "Add1"; 
    DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn(); 
    dc3.DataType = typeof(String); 
    dc3.ColumnName = "Add2"; 

    dt.Columns.Add(dc1); 
    dt.Columns.Add(dc2); 
    dt.Columns.Add(dc3); 

} 



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    Session["Name"] += txtName.Text + "|"; 
    Session["Add1"] += txtAdd1.Text + "|"; 
    Session["Add2"] += txtAdd2.Text + "|"; 
    CreateTable(); 

} 
public void CreateTable() { 

    string[] sa = Session["Name"].ToString().Split('|'); 
    string[] sb = Session["Add1"].ToString().Split('|'); 
    string[] sc = Session["Add2"].ToString().Split('|'); 
    int recordnum = sa.Length; 

    for (int j = 0; j < recordnum - 1; j++) { 

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); 
        dr["Name"] = sa[j].ToString(); 
        dr["Add1"] = sb[j].ToString(); 
        dr["Add2"] = sc[j].ToString(); 
        dt.Rows.Add(dr); 

    } 

    GridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView; 
    GridView1.DataBind(); 

}
```

but this not dynamic and I just can't wrap my hear around this. So I've started with a foreach loop to iterate through rows and cells of table A but not sure how to go about populating individual rows and cells in table B.

```
  foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (row.ItemArray[i] != DBNull.Value)
                _total += Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Risho

Latest Update: As I was writing this post tiny little lighbulbs were turning on in my head and I produced this piece of code. It does not error out but it doesn't work either. For just test purposes I tried to bind to a gridview to see what data I'm getting - but no data. The statis column names are visible in the debugger and I know the source data table has good data. Here the code for yor inspection:

```
DataTable _newDt = new DataTable();

    DataColumn _dc1 = new DataColumn();
    _dc1.DataType = typeof(String);
    _dc1.ColumnName = "Wuc";

    DataColumn _dc2 = new DataColumn();
    _dc2.DataType = typeof(String);
    _dc2.ColumnName = "Wuc Entries";

    DataColumn _dc3 = new DataColumn();
    _dc2.DataType = typeof(String);
    _dc3.ColumnName = "Total Entries";

    _newDt.Columns.Add(_dc1);
    _newDt.Columns.Add(_dc2);

    int _total = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
    {
        DataRow _dr = _newDt.NewRow();

        DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn();
        col1.DataType = typeof(string);
        col1.ColumnName = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

        DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn();
        col2.DataType = typeof(string);
        col2.ColumnName = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();

        DataColumn col3 = new DataColumn();
        col3.DataType = typeof(int);

        for (int i = 2; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (row.ItemArray[i] != DBNull.Value)
                _total += Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[i]);
        }

        col3.ColumnName = _total.ToString();
    }
```

UPDATE #2:

I'v made following changes and but a new error is popped up:

> "Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store  in Wuc Entries Column.  Expected type is Int32."

The issue is that I've delcared the column as String, the data from parent table is in a string format, and so I don't understand why it expects an Int32. (?) Here is the new version:

```
    DataTable _newDt = new DataTable();
    DataRow _dr;

    DataColumn _dc1 = new DataColumn();
    _dc1.DataType = typeof(String);
    _dc1.ColumnName = "Wuc";

    DataColumn _dc2 = new DataColumn();
    _dc2.DataType = typeof(String);
    _dc2.ColumnName = "Wuc Entries";

    DataColumn _dc3 = new DataColumn();
    _dc2.DataType = typeof(Int32);
    _dc3.ColumnName = "Total Entries";

    _newDt.Columns.Add(_dc1);
    _newDt.Columns.Add(_dc2);

    int _total = 0;

    foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
    {
        _dr = _newDt.NewRow();

        _dr["Wuc"] = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        _dr["Wuc Entries"] = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();

        for (int i = 2; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (row.ItemArray[i] != DBNull.Value)
                _total += Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[i]);
        }

        _dr["Total Entries"] = _total;
        _newDt.Rows.Add(_dr);
    }
```

Comment: I think you want row[i], not row.ItemArray[i]

Comment: Just one thought; when you call _newDt.NewRow(), this does not add a row to _newDT; it just creates a new row for you that matches _newDt's schema. You have to then add the row into _newDT via the Rows collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx

Comment: @StephenByrne: the referenced link made it clear to me. I'm surprised I didn't come acoss it maself. So thank you. But... I get an error now. If you get a chance can see my update #2.

Comment: @Risho - can you clarify what line in your code the error is being raised from? Are you sure it's not this:  _total += Convert.ToInt32(row.ItemArray[i]); ??

Comment: @StephenByrne - Is this line: _dr["Wuc Entries"] = row.ItemArray[1].ToString(); Just above the loop.

Comment: Hmm. Can you try using just ``_dr["Wuc Entries"] = row[0].ToString();``
And also check if row.ItemArray[1] is maybe NULL.

Comment: If I change the third column to typeof(String) it works. Doesn't seem to affect the outconme. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much trial and error I was able to make the error go away by changing the trird column to a typeof(String), which really didn't affect the outcome of my data.

But I feel this didn't really solved the issue and I would like to get to the bottom of this some other time.

Comment: LOL, after reading over (and recreating on my system) your code, I came back here and I immediately see now what the problem was all along, look very carefully at this section:
``DataColumn _dc3 = new DataColumn();

    _dc2.DataType = typeof(Int32);``

the second line should be **_dc3** not **_dc2**, so you were in fact trying to assign  a string to an int32!